# Using JSTS isValid() with ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, openlayers

I am trying to configure JSTS to load using ES6 modules so that I don't have to include the entire library.

There are minimal examples of how to do this online, including using an extend function to pull in functionality, however all attempts at getting the isValid method to work have failed:

```
import extend from 'jsts/extend';
import Geometry from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry';
import Valid from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/operation/valid';
import WKTReader from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/WKTReader';    

    extend(Geometry.prototype, {
        buffer: function () {
            return Valid.isValid(this, ...arguments);
        }
    })


    let reader = new WKTReader();
    var geom = reader.read('POLYGON ((80 300, 280 300, 280 80, 80 80, 80 300), (260 280, 180 200, 100 280, 100 100, 260 100, 260 280))');        
    console.log(geom.isValid());
```

Each time all I am getting back is: 
**Uncaught TypeError: geom.isValid is not a function**

Example JSTS ES6 implementation:
https://github.com/DenisCarriere/jsts-es6-example

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that like this :

This example is with the GeoJsonReader but it works similarly with WKTReader

```js
    import * as jsts from 'jsts/dist/jsts';

    const reader = new jsts.io.GeoJSONReader();
    const g = reader.read({
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': [
            [-4.724834116462489, 48.54429850016129],
            [-4.806692014663952, 48.35426654640426],
            [-4.54747533707436, 48.36333181438215],
            [-4.533832354037941, 48.24535748577782],
            [-4.724834116462489, 48.54429850016129]
        ]
      }
    });
    if (! g.geometry.isValid()) {
        // Do what you want when error occurs
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend not importing jsts globally / full lib, but module by module like

`
    import { Geometry as JstsGeometry } from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/geom';
    import { IsValidOp as JstsIsValidOp } from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/operation/valid';
    import { OverlayOp as JstsOverlayOp } from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/operation/overlay';
`

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten it to work to some extent using the following:

```
    import WKTReader from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/WKTReader';
    import Valid from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/operation/valid/IsValidOp';

    const valid = new Valid();

    let reader = new WKTReader();
    var geom = reader.read('POLYGON ((80 300, 280 300, 280 80, 80 80, 80 300), (260 280, 180 200, 100 280, 100 100, 260 100, 260 280))');      

    console.log('Valid: ', valid.isValid(geom));
```

This now returns 'true' for the above Polygon. However if there an error in the Polygon then JSTS just throws an uncaught error, so catching errors from the library is my next issue...

Answer (score 0):

Additional to Alex's answer - might help somebody...

Typing:

```
declare namespace jsts {
  namespace operation {
    namespace valid {
      export class IsValidOp {
        constructor(geom: geom.Geometry);

        static isValid(coord?: geom.Coordinate): boolean;
      }
    }
  }
}

declare module 'jsts' {
  export = jsts;
}
```

Usage:

```
import { IsValidOp as JstsIsValidOp } from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/operation/valid';

if (new JstsIsValidOp(jstsHole).isValid()) {
  ...
}
```

When properly importing JSTS in small portions instead globally, have a look into the operation-namespace/-folder. Especially relate, overlay and valid directories might be helpful.

Importing a full ES5/6 build will also include monkey.js globally which add's convenience-functions to Geometry, but will throw circular-dependency-warnings and increase build-size.